Calendar event missing methods?
I am trying to write a script to manipulate Calendar data. I seem to be retrieving events, but the objects do not implement the expected methods.
Here's my MVE:
const response = Calendar.Events.list(myCalendar, 
   {   timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
       timeMax: (new Date(new Date().getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))).toISOString(),
       showDeleted: false,
       singleEvents: true,
       maxResults: 100,
       orderBy: 'startTime',
       timeZone: 'UTC' }
);
for (event of response.items) {
    Logger.log(event);
    Logger.log(event.summary + " / " + event.getTag("PRInv");
}

I expect Calendar.Events.list.items to be an array of event objects. While the first Logger.log dumps something which looks like it might be an event object:
{
htmlLink=https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=NjR...ldmEuY29t&ctz=UTC, 
description=hello world, 
iCalUID=fgfkgfgkfjgkdjgjd@google.com, 
summary=Colin - test calendar entry, 
kind=calendar#event, 
updated=2024-04-18T21:08:13.098Z, 
end={dateTime=2024-04-19T21:00:00Z, timeZone=America/Los_Angeles}, 
reminders={useDefault=true}, 
id=fgfkgfgkfjgkdjgjd, 
etag="3426948986196000", 
sequence=0.0, 
eventType=default, 
status=confirmed, 
start={timeZone=America/Los_Angeles, dateTime=2024-04-19T20:00:00Z}, 
organizer={self=true, email=symcbean@example.com}, 
created=2024-04-18T21:08:13.000Z, 
creator={email=symcbean@example.com, self=true}
}

However the next line fails with
event.getTag is not a function

Using
Calendar.getEventById(event.id).getTag("PRInv");

I get Calendar.getEventById is not a function even though the docs (again) say that it is a function.
What am I missing here?

Modification points:

I guessed that from your showing script, you might think of Calendar API (Calendar) and Calendar service (CalendarApp) as the same. Unfortunately, those are different.

If you want to use getTag("PRInv") of Calendar service (CalendarApp) with Calendar API, it is required to search a property of extendedProperties. If Logger.log(event.summary + " / " + event.getTag("PRInv"); is modified, it becomes as follows.
Logger.log(event.summary + " / " + event.extendedProperties.shared["PRInv"]);


By the way, Calendar.getEventById(event.id).getTag("PRInv"); cannot be used. In that case, it is required to be as follows.
CalendarApp.getCalendarById(myCalendar).getEventById(event.iCalUID).getTag("PRInv")



When these points are reflected in your showing script, it becomes as follows.
Modified script:
const response = Calendar.Events.list(myCalendar,
  {
    timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
    timeMax: (new Date(new Date().getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))).toISOString(),
    showDeleted: false,
    singleEvents: true,
    maxResults: 100,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
    timeZone: 'UTC'
  }
);
for (event of response.items) {
  Logger.log(event);
  Logger.log(event.summary + " / " + event.extendedProperties.shared["PRInv"]); // and, Logger.log(event.summary + " / " + event.getExtendedProperties().getShared()["PRInv2"]);
}


By this modification, you can see the value of PRInv from the event object.

References:

Calendar Service (CalendarApp)
API Reference of Calendar API (Calendar)


Thank you - yes - I did not realise there were 2 semantically similar classes. Amending the code as you suggested resolved the error.
